# Using SBYZipArchive or other Zip Cocoa Pod in Swift not working

Tags: objective-c, macos, swift, zlib

I have an OSX app that needs to be able to zip and unzip directories, and I figured it would be easy using a cocoapod. I've hit a brick wall.

I've installed *Godzippa, Objective-Zip, zipzap, ZipKit, ZipArchive, SSZipArchive*, and basically every other cocoapod that claims to provide "Zip" functionality, but I've failed to get any of them to work.

I'll share the steps to my failure, and perhaps someone will correct me where I've strayed the correct path:

**1.** Because I am working out of a Swift codebase, I created an Objective-C-Bridging Header, and set the corresponding attribute under Build Settings in the Swift Compiler Section.

**2.** I installed cocoapods in the application and included the desired cocoa pod in the Pod file, ran pod install, and restarted the application using the workspace.

**3.** Inside the bridging header, I imported the necessary objective-c headers of the corresponding cocoa-pod so I can use them in Swift. For example, for SBYZipArchive I had the following in my file I imported the < SBYZipArchive/SBYZipArchive.h> header.

**4.** I try to build the application and it fails on multiple places all referencing the `zlib.h` library.

**5.** I attempted to provide access to the `zlib` library by adding the `libz.dylib` to the Build Phases under Link Binary with Libraries.

**6.** I attempt to build the application, and it still doesn't love me.

To my knowledge the reason why none of these frameworks is working is because they are for some reason failing to access the zlib files that are necessary to do the actual data compression. Thats as far as I've figured out... Any help would be appreciated.

**Update**

I was able to do the zipping without using any of the above packages by simply setting up an NSTask. For those who may care more about zipping than they do using these tools here is how I did it:

```
var task = NSTask()
task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/zip"
task.arguments = ["-r", "/Users/$USERNAME/Documents/$PATHTODIR/zip1.zip", "/Users/$USERNAME/Documents/$PATHTODIR/filesToZip"]
task.launch()
```

When using NSTask you set the launch path to the tool you want to use, and then give the required arguments. so the above task is the equivalent to the command in UNIX:

`zip -r /Users/$USERNAME/Documents/$PATHTODIR/zip1.zip /Users/$USERNAME/Documents/$PATHTODIR/filesToZip`

Obviously swap out the variables I put in there for your own path

**UPDATE**

Although the UNIX zipper works perfect for the mac app, I am pretty sure I need one of the zip packages to be able to do this on iOS

Comment: Why do you need to use a package that somebody else has created?  If you are developing a Mac OS X application, you can use Unix commands.

Comment: I'm happy to try to solve the problem using unix commands, though knowing where to start would be helpful since I know very little about them. On the flip side however, it bothers me that all these packages are done, and I'm struggling to take advantage of them, regardless of how I solve the problem in the end, I'd like to know why this isn't working.

Comment: @El Tomato, Thanks for the advice in using UNIX commands. I was able to use an NSTask and do all the zipping easily myself without these packages. However, my original question of why I couldn't use these packages remains valid, so I will keep the question open.

Comment: @ElTomato Well, I got the UNIX zipper working, but the iOS end of the project now needs to unzip the files, and that will require one of these packages I think.

Comment: You never mentioned before that you were going to zip/unzip files with an iOS application.  So I don't know what to tell you.

Comment: You should be able to use ZipZap 8.0.4 directly as an OS X framework. `import ZipZap` should now work correctly.